# Two domain URL connect single reporting service? is it possible? how to achive this

Tags: reporting-services

i am facing issues in SSRS configuration:

A. i have two domain URL (https://xyz.domain1.com) and (ttps://abc.domain2.com).

B. i have certificate for each domain like

```
   xyz.domain1.com - certificate one (*.domain1.com) -- 443 

   abc.domain2.com - 2nd certificate  (*.domain2.com) -- 443
```

C. In SSRS - i have one virtual directory in web service URL

```
SSRS-> Webservice URL -> virtual directory name : "Report Service"
```

[enter image description here][1]

D. in advance setting
[enter image description here][2]

E. in Report manager URL, i am trying to bind two 443 domain but i cannot

while i bind both url and port 443 then i got this error

*Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: An SSL binding already exists for the specified IP address and port combination.  The existing binding uses a different certificate from the current request. Only one certificate can be used for each IP address and port combination. To correct the problem, either use the same certificate as the existing binding, or remove the existing SSL binding and create a new binding using the certificate of the current request.*

Question:

now i need to connect my report server using two different URL and unique SSL certificate each URL.

But i cant bind this two urls using 443 to connect report server.

I can bind one url and certificate then its working for one URL only.

How do i bind two URLS and certificate to one report server and make it work for two URL's

please help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try ignoring the error on the first URL ('Web Service URL') and proceed to bind the certs to the 'Report Manager URL' as well.  You may have to manually edit the bindings in Advanced Settings, but once you get them looking right in Advanced Settings, SSRS should work.

And a second suggestion, though it looks like you already have done this: be sure the common name (CN) for the wildcard certs are `*.domain1.com` and `*.domain2.com`.  SSRS will only accept host names that match the CN, and in your case, where you're binding 2 certs to same port, the CNs must be different.

Here's a related point for anyone trying to make the multiple hosts in a single subdomain case work: e.g, `https://foo.localdomain/reports` and `https://bar.localdomain/reports`.

Request your SSL cert with Common Name (CN) = *, not the server name or anything specific.  Then list all the permutations of DNS names that you want to support in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN) field.  The url looks funny in SSRS Configuration Manager (`https:+:443`), but it Works on the Wire(tm).

If you specify some non-wildcard for the CN, you'll get 'resource not found' error tryng to connect, although the SSL handshake will work.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the objective you need a **Multi-Domain SSL** or **Wildcard SSL** certificate, for example:

Multi-Domain SSL(Multiple Domains)

- xyz.domain1.com
- abc.domain2.com

Wildcard SSL(Sub-domains)

- xyz.domain1.com
- abc.domain1.com

Reference:

- [Multiple Domain (UCC) SSL](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate-3908)
- [Secure multiple domains and
  sub-domains on one certificate](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl/wildcard-multi-domain/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, currently i have wildcard SSL, but two SSL certificates are pointing to different domain. like 1st certificate -> *.domain1.com and 2nd certificate -> *.domain2.com. so this wont work?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, currently i have wildcard SSL, but two SSL certificates are pointing to different domain. like 1st certificate -> *.domain1.com and 2nd certificate -> *.domain2.com. so this wont work? can i use different port (port no:444) then will it work?

Comment: yes, you can. after changing the port in Reporting Services Configuration Manager.